# Validate two Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I was developing an application, in that I am strucked at validating two inputs to `removeClass` to button.

```js
$('input#firstInput').blur(function(){
    tmpval2 = $('input#secondInput').val();
    tmpval = $(this).val();
 
    if(tmpval == '') {
        $("#myButton").addClass('disabled')
    }
    else if(tmpval2 == ''){
        $("#myButton").addClass('disabled')
    } else {
        $("#myButton").removeClass('disabled')
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"> Validate Two Inputs</h3>
      </div>
  
  
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="text" id="firstInput" placeholder="First Value"  />
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="secondInput" placeholder="Second Value" />
      <br><br>
      <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-success disabled"> Send
      </button>
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the code what I developed for that.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/zeasts/kgynth5x/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably be **listening for keypresses**, then checking whether the value of the first input or the second input are empty. If they are, then disable the button. Otherwise, both inputs have values so the disabled class can be removed.

The only changes to the HTML is the fact that I've added the class `input-field` to all input fields that should be checked.

```js
$('.input-field').keyup(function() {
    var firstValue = $('#firstInput').val(),
        secondValue = $('#secondInput').val();

     if (firstValue == '' || secondValue == '') {
         $("#myButton").addClass('disabled');
     } else {
         $("#myButton").removeClass('disabled');
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title"> Validate Two Inputs</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <input type="text" class="input-field" id="firstInput" placeholder="First Value" />
          <br><br>
          <input type="text" class="input-field" id="secondInput" placeholder="Second Value" />
          <br><br>
          <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-success disabled">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: its checking only if the values are present, if it is null still I can click the Send `button`

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain Sorry, typo. Should've been keyup not keypress

Answer (score 1):

Try this code or go through below fiddle link

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgynth5x/9/)

JAVASCRIPT Code -

```
$('input').blur(function(){
        $("#myButton").removeClass('disabled');
        tmpval = $(this).val();
        if(tmpval == '') {
            $("#myButton").addClass('disabled');
        }
      if($(this).siblings('input').val() == ''){
        $("#myButton").addClass('disabled');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Looking simple and the best

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain Happy to help you :)

Comment: It will not work if you have some other inputs like *remember me*

Comment: @Justinas Is the accepted answer work if you have some other inputs like remember me?

Answer (score 0):

First remove classes and later add it checking both inputs at once

```js
$('.inputs').change(function() {
  $("#myButton").removeClass('disabled');

  var isValid = false;

  $('.inputs').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() && $(this).val().length) {
      isValid = true;

      return false; // same as break;
    }
  });

  if (!isValid) {
    $("#myButton").addClass('disabled')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title"> Validate Two Inputs</h3>
        </div>


        <div class="panel-body">
          <input type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="First Value" />
          <br><br>
          <input type="text" class="inputs" placeholder="Second Value" />
          <br><br>
          <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-success disabled"> Send
      </button>
        </div>


      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: both inputs are not validating.

Comment: Only works for one input field and doesn't work if the user back spaces the characters from the input field. Maybe make isValid true initially. If a field is empty, make it false and check against that

Comment: I need for the both cases

Answer (score 0):

You Need to do it on change event.
There is my solution - fast :)

Example:

```
$('input.required').keyup(function(){

/* Validate all required fields */
var err = 0;
$('input.required').each(function(){
    var input = $(this);
  if(input.val().length == 0){
    err++;
  }
});

if(!err){
    $('#myButton').removeClass('disabled');
}
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kgynth5x/11/

Comment: Nice solution! One problem is that the button is still clickable when a user removes all characters from the field

Comment: Its Simple to fix it :)
$('#myButton').prop('disabled', true);

And after removing class set it to false :)

Comment: Ok, i fixed answer, now its ok

Answer (score 0):

Check if this might solves your issue

Thanks

```js
$('input#firstInput').keyup(function(){
  var tmpval = $(this).val();
    var tmpval1 = "";
    $('input#secondInput').keyup(function(){
       tmpval1 = $(this).val(); 
       checkValid(tmpval,tmpval1);
    });
    checkValid(tmpval,tmpval1);
});

function checkValid(tmpval,tmpval1){
  if(tmpval == '' || tmpval1 == '') {
         $("#myButton").addClass('disabled')
 }
  else {
      $("#myButton").removeClass('disabled')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"> Validate Two Inputs</h3>
      </div>
  
  
    <div class="panel-body">
      <input type="text" id="firstInput" placeholder="First Value"  />
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="secondInput" placeholder="Second Value" />
      <br><br>
      <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-success disabled"> Send
      </button>
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```